# Angular 4 style overriding addons

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

while developping an angular 4 app using angular-cli + sass, i have this problem with multiple plugins. so here is the scenario:

I have a main `style.scss` file that import other styles files ..., so if i want to modify a plugin style, let say a slider component styles, i will create a slider.scss and import it into my main style.scss file, the problem is that the imported component css is injected into the browser after my main css file. so when i want to modify something i need to add `!important` to the rule.

here is a snapshot of chrome inspect css tool:

```
element.style {
    left: 100%;
}
<style>…</style>
.noUi-marker-horizontal.noUi-marker-large {
    height: 15px;
}
<style>…</style>
.noUi-marker-horizontal.noUi-marker {
    margin-left: -1px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 5px;
}

<style>…</style>
.noUi-marker-horizontal.noUi-marker-large {
    height: 10px !important;
}
```

my custom css is the last one.

---

I want to know if there is a way to load my css style file after the components css file, i can use precedence rule to make it work, but i want to know if there is a more clean way.

Comment: make use of view encapuslation [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/host)

Comment: @RahulSingh i don't want to completely remove external styles, i just want to modify some css property.

Comment: You can with host component modify the child style using host deep

Comment: @RahulSingh could you provide me a link to read about hot deep?

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/guide/component-styles